# Does SDL require any sound server like PulseAudio to play audio?

Tags: linux, audio, alsa

I'm trying to make an MP3 player on top of the Linux kernel and `busybox` using the SDL and SMPEG libraries.

Does SDL work on top of the kernel or it needs PulseAudio?

I have just built a C program which plays mp3 files one by one from a directory. But when I put it on my ARM board nothing is happening, it justs hang in console, even `plaympeg` didn't work. 
But when I am using

```
plaympeg --novideo song.mp3
```

it shows

```
Couldn't init SDL audio: No available audio device
```

Can anyone guide me?

Answer (score 1):

SDL doesn't need PulseAudio per se; however, it can use PA if it's available. It seems that SDL [could run](http://forums.libsdl.org/viewtopic.php?t=3974&sid=c06d7d2c75884b43d50e74a9d6301926) [without X](http://lists.libsdl.org/pipermail/sdl-libsdl.org/2006-October/058298.html) if a framebuffer is available.

You could begin from the [examples at SDL's page](http://www.libsdl.org/intro.en/usingsound.html) to check whether it's a problem of your ARM board, and you probably will need to do other debugging on your audio player program (I would think it's a codec issue).

Since you're running on a Raspberry Pi, you might try [this](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/44/why-is-my-audio-sound-output-not-working) to see if you get audio working (I don't have my RPi here, so I can't test it).

Comment: can u tell me why `plaympeg` is not working??

Comment: I can't tell from the very little information you gave (what ARM board are you using? Which version of the Linux kernel? Which distro? etc...). More information (such as stack traces) would be needed.

Comment: linux 3.2.27 board raspberry pi, distro is my custom

Comment: it shows `Couldn't init SDL audio: No available audio device`

Comment: You say you're using a Raspberry Pi. Updated the answer with a link that may be relevant